# A word for a word describing a property of a list entry

Tags: single-word-requests

Let's say I have a list like this:

> > PEOPLE
>
> Name: Bert
>
> Age: 762
>
> Profession: Blacksmith
>
> > 
>
> Name: Yvonne
>
> Age: 23
>
> Profession: Clown puncher
>
> > ORGANIZATIONS
>
> Name: The Whatever Thing
>
> For-profit: Yes
>
> Revenue: 5$
>
> > 
>
> Name: The Red Cross
>
> For-profit: No
>
> Revenue: 349853969483$

What would be a good word for the "property descriptors" Name, Age, Profession, For-profit, and Revenue? Also is there a better word than "title" for PEOPLE and ORGANIZATIONS?

Comment: *Label* and *Category*, respectively.

Comment: Anything wrong with "heading" and "property"?

Comment: Pretty sure this question came up before, about a month a go.

Comment: @Lawrence I prefer your terms out of the ones suggested. If you put it in an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'property descriptors' are generically called **labels** and the 'people' and 'organizations' are **categories** that you have split your data into.

> **Label**
> : a word or phrase that describes or identifies something or someone [- M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/label)
>
> **Category**
> 2 :  a division within a system of classification [- M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/category)

Answer (score 2):

In my database designing days I called them "attributes".  I prefer "individual" to "people" or "person" in this context.  If someone has a better word than "organization" I'd be happy to learn it.

Answer (score 0):

For PEOPLE, I would use **private persons** (or "private individuals").

For ORGANIZATIONS, **Companies and organizations** is perhaps preferable.

As previously proposed, the information fields may be referred as "attributes" or "properties".